# Aerospike filter expression on boolean fields not working

Tags: java, database, filter, nosql, aerospike

I've written the following Aerospike filter in Java. Both `Field1` and `Field2` are booleans. For some reason, the "filterByField.ValidBoth" condition does not yield true, although the record matches the criteria.

Since it's a boolean, I'm using 1 for true and 0 for false.

Am I missing something?

```
public Exp getFilterByFieldFilter(FilterByField filterByField) {
    if (filterByField == null || "".equals(filterByField)) {
        return Exp.val(true);
    }
    if (filterByField == filterByField.All) {
        return Exp.val(true);
    } else if (filterByField == filterByField.ValidBoth) {
        return Exp.and(Exp.eq(Exp.intBin("Field1"), Exp.val(0)),
                Exp.eq(Exp.intBin("Field2"), Exp.val(0)));
    }
}
```

From what I can see from database results through AQL, those which are not set to true are not reflected in the result set.

Should I write my filter is a different way to check this condition? If so what would that condition look like?

I tried checking for Exp.val(NULL) but got error.

Here's my database result set through AQL

```
 [
        {
          "PK": "1",
          "Name": "ABC",
          "Field1": 1,
          "Field2": 1
        },
        {
          "PK": "2",
          "Name": "EFG",
          "Field1": 1
        },
        {
          "PK": "3",
          "Name": "XYZ",
        }
        
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If bin names Field1 and Field2 contain boolean values then your expression should be constructed in this fashion (whatever the desired logic is):

```
Exp.eq(Exp.boolBin("Field1"), Exp.val(false))
```

I tested the construct below, seems to work for me:

```
WritePolicy wPolicy = new WritePolicy();

Bin b1 = new Bin("Field1", Value.get(0));
Bin b2 = new Bin("Field2", Value.get(0));
Bin b3 = new Bin("Data", Value.get("data"));

wPolicy.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.REPLACE;

client.put(wPolicy, key, b1, b2, b3);

//client.put(wPolicy, key, b1, b3);

Exp condFilter = Exp.and( 
Exp.eq(Exp.intBin("Field1"),Exp.val(0) ),
Exp.eq(Exp.intBin("Field2"),Exp.val(0) )
);

Policy policy = new Policy();

policy.filterExp = Exp.build(condFilter);
Record record = client.get(policy, key);
System.out.println("Read back the record.");

System.out.println("Record values are:");
System.out.println(record);

//Get record without filter condition
record = client.get(null, key);
System.out.println(record);
```

Valid condition:

```
Read back the record.
Record values are:
(gen:18),(exp:0),(bins:(Field1:0),(Field2:0),(Data:data))
(gen:18),(exp:0),(bins:(Field1:0),(Field2:0),(Data:data))
```

Invalid Condition (no Field2 bin):

```
Read back the record.
Record values are:
null
(gen:19),(exp:0),(bins:(Field1:0),(Data:data))
```

Comment: Right, 1 and 0 are considered 64 bit integers. You have to use true or false, expressions are very type strict. While a dynamically typed system would have been easier on the end user, it would have also been easier for the end user to make catastrophic mistakes, so we opted for a strict type system to prevent a certain class of mistakes.

Comment: If you have data which is stored as 1 or 0, you would need to convert it to boolean by comparing with 0. Eg. `NE(intBin, intVal(0))`

Comment: If you wanted to convert to using boolean over time (which is a bit more efficient in storage (1 byte less iirc)). Then you could use `OR(boolBin(bin), NE(intBin(bin), intVal(0))`.

Comment: @kporter thanks for the suggestion, This makes sense but for some reason it's not working for me. I have edited my post with latest info. can you please suggest any solutions for that?